# Creating custom and stylized GUI in Android Apps

Tags: android

Guys, whant to get any kind of info about sources in global net about developing stylized GUI, using any kind of tools (graphical editors: photoshop, gimp, Illustrator; android resources, such as drawable and so on), web-sites, books, videos, would be great if it has samples.

Thanks everybody for any kind of information)))

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "developing stylized GUI"?

Comment: he probably means he wants info on where to start to do something that does not look stock android. The question is generic, but a great one imho.

Answer (score 2):

Um, if I understand you properly, you want to know how you create GUI's within android correct? If thats the case check out [this site](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/). I has some pretty good looking GUI's and tutorials with source.